# Creating a custom CloudWatch Event to monitor every new commit for GitHub repository instead of CodeCommit repo state change

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda, amazon-codepipeline

Could you please assist me in understanding if it is possible to create a custom CloudWatch Event to monitor every new commit for GitHub repositories instead of CodeCommit repo state changes? It has always seemed to me that cloudwatch events are used primarily for AWS services, but I wondered if it was possible to implement the below link functionality with GitHub instead of CodeCommit.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/.
In general, I would like to invoke codepipeline via the commandline by revoking console access, limiting access to GitHub, and keeping all cloudpipeline JSON files in a repository and committing with the updated environment variable and then releasing the change instantly.

If python can be used to build functionality for GitHub repo state changes and executing them using lambdas, is that possible? If anyone has any relevant examples, please share.